# Cocosmotion cloned from github repository does not work

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, rubymotion

I cloned cocosmotion repository from github, but I can't get it to work. I am almost totally new to mac os, xcode and iOS development, so there can be things that I am missing right now).
I have XCode 4.5 installed, downloaded cocos2d and installed it's template so that now I can create cocos2d projects from templates. Also I bought RubyMotion and RubyMine with it;s support, but demo project from github does not compile with the following error:

/Users/DarkDeny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/DarkDeny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rake simulator
Build ./build/iPhoneSimulator-6.0-Development
Build vendor/cocos2d-iphone
ERROR! Building vendor project vendor/cocos2d-iphone' failed to create at least one.a' library.

Process finished with exit code 1

I tried to compare cocos2d which I downloaded by myself from it's site, found that resources are missing, after adding them to cocos2d folder structure. I got XCode compiling cocos2d within cocosmotion-master folder to compile successfully, but rubymotion project still reports the same error from above.
What am I missing? What could be the root cause of the problem?

Comment: "I am almost totally new to mac os, xcode and iOS development" … which makes me wonder, why are you heading in the Ruby direction? It's always going to be easier to work with the tools & languages of the target platform - even if they're new - than to forcibly use a known language (I assume that's Ruby in your case) and try to sneak in through the backdoor where nobody's looking (meaning hardly anyone can help). Your best option: contact the author. Ask if CocosMotion is anywhere near production ready.

Comment: Surely i tried, but there is no any answer at the moment. That's why I decided to ask SO community - may be someone saw similar problem and know how to solve it. And about a language - I think that Ruby is quite new to mac/ios development, then ObjC. And my known language is C#, not Ruby.

Comment: Try opening Cocos2d in Xcode once and then closing it. It seems to set up some configuration that RubyMotion need to build. You also want to make sure the project builds correctly in Xcode. Head's up as I've been through this, it's very challenging when you're new to so many things, esp. Xcode. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to start from scratch and use cocoapods with RubyMotion. This will definitely work as I was able to check. cocosmotion repo from github is deprecated since there is a pod of cocos2d from its' creators.

Comment: While using the cocoapod for cocos2d is good (better than deprecated cocosmotion), there are still a number of quirks to get it set up and running.  You might want to check out the recently released Joybox wrapper for Cocos2d and Box2d https://github.com/rubymotion/Joybox